# как передать две функции в onChange react redux

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

Хочу понять, как в `onChange=` передать две функции, когда пытаюсь написать туда `check` `this.check()` или даже `onChange={event => this.check(event)}` то первая функция не работает так, как нужно, как-будто в неё не приходит эвент, при этом одна она там абсолютно нормально работает

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import CountReducer from '../reducers/CountReducer'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
export default class Counter extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.check = this.check.bind(this);
      }  
    check(event)
    { 
        this.props.onUpdateClick(event.target.value);
        this.props.onLink(event.target.value);
    }
    render() {

        const {count, wish_value, onIncreaseClick,onLink,onUpdateClick} = this.props
        if (count === 1){
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span>{count}</span>
                    <button  onClick={onIncreaseClick}>Increase</button>
                    <button onClick={onLink}>Поиск</button>
                    <button onClick={onLink}>
                        <Link  to="/search">Поиск</Link> 
                    </button>
                    <input value={wish_value} type="text" onChange={onUpdateClick} onClick={onLink}/>
                </div>

            </div>
        )} else { return (
<div>
                <div>
                    <span>{count}</span>
                    <button  onClick={onIncreaseClick}>Increase</button>
                    <button onClick={onLink}>Поиск</button>
                    <button onClick={onLink}>
                        <Link to="/" onClick={alert("неверное имя п")}>Поиск</Link>
                    </button>
                    <input value={wish_value} type="text" onChange={onUpdateClick} onClick={onLink}/>
                </div>

            </div>)
        }
    }
}



export const updateTodo = (wish_value) => {
    return {
        type:'update',
        wish_value: wish_value
    }
}


export const linkTodo = (wish_value) => {
    return {
        type: 'link',
        wish_value: wish_value
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
    onIncreaseClick: () => dispatch(actions.increaseTodo()),
    onLink: () => dispatch(actions.linkTodo()),
    onUpdateClick: event => dispatch((
        actions.updateTodo(event.target.value)

    ))
}
```

}

Comment: не нашел, а где вызывается check? На каком событии?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov вызывал `check` вместо `onUpdateClick` в `<input onChange`, но там он не работал, точнее не работал именно `onUpdateClick`

Comment: тогда `onChange={this.check}` , а в `onUpdateClick` в функции `check` вы передаете уже готовый `event.target.value`, а внутри `onUpdateCheck` вы ожидаете `event` и снова пытаетесь получить из него `target`. Но пришла то уже строка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось, спасибо @DmitryKozlov,
изменения, которые я внёс:

```
check(event)
    { 
        this.props.onUpdateClick(event);
        this.props.onLink(event.target.value);
    }


<input value={wish_value} type="text" onChange={this.check} onClick={onLink}/>
```